# Smallest ring containing collection of subsets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given any collection $C$ of subsets of a set $X$, show that there is a smallest ring of sets $R$ containing $C$. (That is, $R$ has the property that it contains $C$, and any ring that contains $C$ contains $R$.) Describe explicitly how to construct $R$ from $C$.

We must take all finite unions and differences of the sets in $C$, call the new collection $C_1$. Then take all finite unions and differences of the sets in $C_1$, call the new collection $C_2$. And so on, to $C_3,C_4,\ldots$.

Clearly any ring must contain $C,C_1,C_2,\ldots$. If we can show that the process stops at some $C_n$, we have our smallest ring of sets containing $C$. But why must it stop?

Comment: Your strategy is intuitive, but you captured the problem with it: it's messy. It's easier if you try to consider the intersection of all rings that contain $C$. Then show that intersection is a ring and that it has the property you are looking for. Edit: Also before claiming your intersection exists, show that there is a ring that contains $C$ (namely the power set of $X$).

Comment: @minimalrho I agree with you - that strategy is much simpler to reason.